# OpenGL ES Android - Texture not loaded (rendered black)

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, textures

As in the title, I'm using OpenGL ES (2) on Android (7.0).
Apparently, though, I have some problems when trying to load a texture from the asset folder.
This is the code I'm using

```
public static int loadTexture(final AssetManager assetManager, final String img)
{
    final int[] textureHandle = new int[1];
    glGenTextures(1, textureHandle, 0);

    if(textureHandle[0] == 0)
        throw new RuntimeException("Error loading texture");

    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inScaled = false;

    try
    {
        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(assetManager.open(img));
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[0]);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

        bitmap.recycle();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    textures.put(img, textureHandle[0]);

    return textureHandle[0];
}
```

This is called from `onSurfaceCreated` as I know I need a running OpenGL context

Most of the time this works and gives me this result

[image: working texture]

but a considerable number of other times I get this

[image]

No Exception is thrown.

I know the problem is not depending on the 3D model nor the texture because I've tried other ones. The only thing I can do when this happens is to restart my App a couple of times.

I've tried googling around but with no results. I know I could try to implement another loading function, but first I'd like to understand why this is not ok and where it's not working.

---

If you think this could depends on the code I'm using to render the scene here it is (no VAOs because I need to support older devices and OpenGL ES 2):

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, model.getCoordsVBO());
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, model.getTextureVBO());
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, model.getNormalsVBO());
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, entity.getTexture());
loadFloat(loc_textureSampler, 0);

if(model.getIndicesBuffer() != null)
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, model.getIndicesVBO());
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, model.getVertexCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
}
else
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, model.getVertexCount());

glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

Comment: Have you checked is there are any glErrors?

Comment: @Reaper yes, no error

Answer (score 1):

What I didn't say (because I thought it was irrelevant) is that I had a little more code ad the top of the function...

```
if(textures.containsKey(img))
    return textures.get(img);
```

and at the bottom

```
textures.put(img, textureHandle[0]);
```

I thought it was intelligent to keep track of the textures, so I could have called this load function anytime I needed a texture and if I had already loaded it, it would have returned it without loading again.

This could work on a desktop application, but I haven't considered that on Android the garbage collector could delete the texture from OpenGL when I exit the app so that when the activity restarts it wouldn't be there anymore.

Removing that `HashMap` solved the problem, demonstrating that the actual reading and loading code had nothing to do with that black thing.